# negative number be an element even if the set contains only positive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can -12 be an element of this set.
A = {12,13,14,15}

From what I understand that this set is finite and doesn't extend into negative numbers so my thinking is that -12 cannot be an element of the set.

Comment: The set describes exactly which elements are in it. In particular, $x \in A \iff x = 12$ or $x=13$ or $x=14$ or $x=15$.

Comment: No it can't -- otherwise it would have been explicitly listed as an element of the set.